# Algorithm for iteratively distributing $5$ units to two variables

Tags: algorithms

Please point me to the right place if this isn't the right one to ask in.

- There are 2 initial integer variables (the values of the two can be changed). $a = 4$ and $b = 1$
- There's a function. Each run of the function can distribute a total of $5$ to $a$ and $b$.
- So any positive integer combination of $5$ is possible.
- So a run for example could be $a = a + 1$ and $b = b + 4$.
- Another run could be $a = a + 3$ and $b = b + 2$.
- Another run could be $b = b + 5$.
- Also, the function increases $a$ by $1$ at the end of each iteration. (So at each run, $a$ will increase by $1$).

What is the lowest number of runs that could be done such that $a \geq 99$ and $b \geq 99$?

Here's sample code where I did a super simple inefficient approach that's also probably not correct/doesn't give the lowest number possible:

```
public static void Main()
{
    int core = 4;
    int shell = 1;
    int counter = 1;
    while (core < 99 || shell < 99)
    {
        ++core;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            if ((shell + 1) <= 99)
            {
                shell++;
            }
            else
            {
                core++;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"counter: {counter} | core: {core} | shell: {shell}");
        ++counter;
    }
}
//////////// output of above:
    counter: 1 | core: 5 | shell: 6
    counter: 2 | core: 6 | shell: 11
    counter: 3 | core: 7 | shell: 16
    counter: 4 | core: 8 | shell: 21
    counter: 5 | core: 9 | shell: 26
    counter: 6 | core: 10 | shell: 31
    counter: 7 | core: 11 | shell: 36
    counter: 8 | core: 12 | shell: 41
    counter: 9 | core: 13 | shell: 46
    counter: 10 | core: 14 | shell: 51
    counter: 11 | core: 15 | shell: 56
    counter: 12 | core: 16 | shell: 61
    counter: 13 | core: 17 | shell: 66
    counter: 14 | core: 18 | shell: 71
    counter: 15 | core: 19 | shell: 76
    counter: 16 | core: 20 | shell: 81
    counter: 17 | core: 21 | shell: 86
    counter: 18 | core: 22 | shell: 91
    counter: 19 | core: 23 | shell: 96
    counter: 20 | core: 26 | shell: 99
    counter: 21 | core: 32 | shell: 99
    counter: 22 | core: 38 | shell: 99
    counter: 23 | core: 44 | shell: 99
    counter: 24 | core: 50 | shell: 99
    counter: 25 | core: 56 | shell: 99
    counter: 26 | core: 62 | shell: 99
    counter: 27 | core: 68 | shell: 99
    counter: 28 | core: 74 | shell: 99
    counter: 29 | core: 80 | shell: 99
    counter: 30 | core: 86 | shell: 99
    counter: 31 | core: 92 | shell: 99
    counter: 32 | core: 98 | shell: 99
    counter: 33 | core: 104 | shell: 99
```

Comment: I encourage you to [edit] your post to provide a more descriptive title.

Comment: 1. Please specify whether a run can distribute 0 to a and 5 to b, or vice versa.  2. Please explain what you mean by "at the end".  At the end of each run (once per run)?  After performing all runs (once overall)?

Comment: the sixth point, b = b + 5 covers that. you can give 0 to any

Comment: also added sample code with print variables after each run to demonstrate what I mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you add $1$ to $a$ at each iteration, while $b$ can only be increased summing a portion of $5$ at each iterations, the idea is that of bringing $b$ to $99$ and then take care of $a$.

This is an outline for the algorithm:

1. while $b<95$ add $5$ to $b$. As a consequence, you will add $1$ to $a$
2. if $b<99$ (so it would be between $95$ and $98$ add to $b$ the remaining quantity in order to get $b=99$. Add the remaining part to $a$
3. while $a<99$ add $5$ to $a$ ($+1$ at the end of the run$

This algorithm provide an optimal solution. In your case where $a=4$ and $b=1$:

1. Step 1 executes $\lfloor \frac{98}{5}\rfloor=19$ runs in order to get to $b=96$. As a consequence, $a$ is increased by $19$. So, at the end of first step we have done $19$ runs and we have $a=23$, $b=96$.
2. Step 2 executes one run, adding $3$ to $b$ and $2$ to $a$. At the end of the run $a$ is increased by $1$. So, at the end of second step we have done $20$ runs and we have $a=26$, $b=99$.
3. Step 3 executes $\lceil\frac{99-26}{6}\rceil=\lceil\frac{73}{6}\rceil=13$ runs. At the end of third step we have done $33$ runs and we have $a\geq 99$ and $b=99$.

So 33 is the minimum number of runs.

Comment: I edited my question with sample code, got answer of 33, but  i think my way is not good, there should be a much better way.

Comment: @whatdafq of course you get $33$, you are adding $6$ at each iterations:  at first run you add $1$ to core and $5$ to shell, same in second run.

Comment: that's the last point (i've edited, added more explanation):
- Also, the function increases a by 1 at the end no matter what independently of the distribution.

Comment: @whatdafq the text was not clear to me. Now I think I understood and I edited my solution. Check it

Comment: Thanks. How about if b has initial value of 4, or 7, or maybe even change a? Will the same logic work?

Comment: @whatdafq yes, of course. The algorithm outline I proposed never make any assumption on $a$'s and $b$'s values and the fundamental concept behind it is that you have to increase $b$ using the $5$ units per run, otherwise you can't increase it, so it makes sense to start from $b$ and bring it to $99$ and then operate on $a$.